# Flutter/Flame limiting the drag area in a game

Tags: flutter, flame

I am trying to move my player by dragging, but I don't want my player to go out of the screen. How can I limit it in a decent way?

```
void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  if(game.screenSize.width >= playerRect.right && playerRect.left >= 0
      && game.screenSize.height >= playerRect.bottom && playerRect.top >= 0) {
    playerRect = playerRect.translate(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy);
  } else { 
    playerRect = playerRect.translate(-details.delta.dx*4.2, -details.delta.dy*4.2);
  }
}
```

I came up with this solution but as you know it is not cool. I appriciate any kind help.

Comment: I don't think your code is that bad, but I think your player could get stuck outside of the screen if it manages to move far enough outside of it within one update and then change direction of the drag. Because then it could end up in the else case in every iteration. You could add the delta to the if-check to avoid that, but there is probably some better way to all together compare the two rectangles and know the translation from there.

Comment: The problem of this code is what you said. Whatever is the minus delta value, in any case my player goes out of the screen. It does not look like a good experience when the player is shaking at the borders of the screen. the more if cases cause slowness on the move of the player. I have found nothing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to see another user of our game engine! The delta also has to be taken into consideration in the check. Something like this should work:

```
void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  final delta = details.delta;
  final size = game.screenSize
  double translateX = delta.dx;
  double translateY = delta.dy;
  // Make sure that the player never goes outside of the screen in the X-axis
  if (playerRect.right + delta.dx >= size.width) {
      translateX = size.width - playerRect.right; 
  } else if (playerRect.left + delta.dx <= 0) {
      translateX = -playerRect.left; 
  }
  // Make sure that the player never goes outside of the screen in the Y-axis
  if (playerRect.bottom + delta.dy >= size.height) {
      translateY = size.height - playerRect.bottom; 
  } else if (playerRect.top + delta.dy <= 0) {
      translateY = -playerRect.top; 
  }
  playerRect = playerRect.translate(translateX, translateY);
}
```

If you have more in-depth questions I suggest that you join our discord too:
https://discord.gg/pxrBmy4

Comment: playerRect.left + delta.dx > 0 and playerRect.top + delta.dy > 0 should be playerRect.top + delta.dy <(=) 0 and playerRect.left + delta.dx <(=) 0.  "<" should be used instead of ">". this code works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that it worked, updated the code according to your comment.